# convert Excel decimal date time into time.Time

Tags: excel, datetime, go

While parsing an excel file in Golang, a date time column is getting read as `44531.553587963` which actually represents the time `12/01/2021 13:17:10`.

How can I convert this decimal representation to `time.Time` object in go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var in float64 = 44531.553587963
excelEpoch := time.Date(1899, 12, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
tm := excelEpoch.Add(time.Duration(in * float64(24 * time.Hour)))
fmt.Println(tm) // 2021-12-01 13:17:10.000003072 +0000 UTC
```

Excel time is (usually, barring weird legacy versions of the format) measured in days since 12/30/1899. It was meant to be  so that `1.0` would equal midnight at 1900-01-01, but someone used a faulty leap year algorithm that thought that February 1900 had 29 days, when it only had 28, so all dates after that point were off-by-1. Rather than break existing spreadsheets, they left that bug in place, so to get correct dates (post-1900) you have to offset the epoch back by one day, so `1.0` equals 1989-12-31 and `0.0` equals 1989-12-30.

Anyway, once we know the epoch it's just a little type juggling to convert one day in nanoseconds to a float, multiply, and then convert back to a duration, and add that duration to the epoch.

Comment: A little story around the topic: [blog post by Joel Spolsky](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2006/06/16/my-first-billg-review/)

Comment: Other way to do this is to convert to Unix timestamp: `tm := time.Unix(int64((in - 25569) * 86400), 0)`